# Removing EMF dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, emf

I am trying to clean a Java project from its EMF dependencies. I set the option "Suppress EMF Types" in .genmodel file in Eclipse to true and regenerated the code. This converted EMF types to Java types such as EList to List. But there is a section in the project which uses EMF classes as follows:

```
        VulnerabilityDB db = NvdFactory.eINSTANCE.createVulnerabilityDB();
        XMIResource resource = new XMIResourceImpl(URI.createFileURI("target/test.vdb"));
        resource.getContents().add(db);
        resource.save(Collections.emptyMap());
```

I think I need to reimplement this using Java only libraries but I am not familiar with EMF and I didn't get the exact objective of this section. How can I fix this part?

Answer (score 1):

That is the minimum bottleneck/requirement you have encountered. I would suggest to create a facade to hide the remaining EMF APIs.
For example:

```
interface VDBService {
    void createDB(VulnerabilityDB db, String uri);
    VulnerabilityDB loadDB(String uri);
}
```